# Generate CRUD from Existing JPA entities with roo

Tags: spring-roo

I have a Spring MVC project with JPA (hibernate provider) for the persistence layer. I would like to add the CRUD Web app. Is possible to use spring-roo to generate the CRUD web app from my jpa entities? if yes can you point me to an example/tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap your entities with Roo Services, see [section 10.3](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-layers.html).  Web mvc scaffolding should then detect the services and generate the CRUD user interface for you.